# Do methods Merge and Join make sense for a path class?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a path class which currently has a method called `Combine` which works like the .NET Path.Combine. If an argument is an absolute path (roughly because it begins with `\`), then it replaces anything to the left, so:

```
Combine("c:\folder", "two"); // produces "c:\folder\two"
Combine("c:\folder", "\two"); // produces "c:\two"
```

I'm worried this will catch people out who expect the second to also produce `c:\folder\two' and am wondering how to protect against this.

An alternative design would be to have an enum param to select behaviour:

```
enum CombineMethod { respectAbsolute, ignoreAbsolute };

Path Combine(CombineMethod combineMethod, Path a, Path b);
```

That seems a bit wordy, so another alternative I'm considering is having two methods:

```
Path Join( Path a, Path b );
Path Merge( Path a, Path b);

Merge("c:\folder", "two"); // produces "c:\folder\two"
Merge("c:\folder", "\two"); // produces "c:\two"

Join("c:\folder", "two"); // produces "c:\folder\two"
Join("c:\folder", "\two"); // produces "c:\folder\two"
```

Do any of these alternatives seem at all intuitive, do you think it would be easy to accidentally call the wrong function. Or do you have better design suggestions so that users can get the behaviour they want without accidentally picking the wrong behaviour?

Comment: The usual (on Windows) is to have one function that dissects a path into drive, path, and filename. From there, the result of merging (for example) one drive with another path and a third file name is straightforward and obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that this:

```
Combine("c:\folder", "\two"); // produces "c:\two"
```

Isn't combine any more, it's substitute.

The whole point of having a Combine method is so that the consumer doesn't have to worry about dealing with the path separators at all.  These should all have the same result:

```
Combine("c:\folder", "two");
Combine("c:\folder\", "two");
Combine("c:\folder", "\two");
Combine("c:\folder\", "\two");
```

What you want is a function to extract the drive letter and then combine the result of that.  In .NET, that look like this:

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetPathRoot("c:\folder"), "\two");
```

Comment: You've offered one possible motivation for having a Combine method.  An alternative motivation is, "The user has provided me with a path which may or may not be an absolute path.  Given an initial path, how should the user's path be interpreted?" This is not an unreasonable interpretation; it's useful for things like `cd` (change directory) style commands.  Mind you, not caring about path separators in the initial path is a valid benefit.  Note that this is the approach taken by [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) in C#.

Comment: Depends on what you combine: Is the second part a path or is it only a part of a path? Both make some sense, but the second is trivial. And if the point of the method was the path-separators, it would accept an arbitrary number of path-components to combine.

Comment: How would you name the function which, given a starting directory and a potentially relative path, returns the resulting path then? And no, doing that manually every single time is not a valid option, so your `Path.Combine(Path.GetPathRoot("c:\folder"), "\two");`-example is simply irrelevant.

Comment: You would have to define how Combine would work in the case of two absolute paths.  .NET's Path.Combine will return only the second argument if it's an absolute path.  Personally, I think that is unintuitive. I would say that trying to combine two absolute paths does not make sense and have the function throw an exception.

Comment: There's no reason you can't allow an arbitrary number of strings to combine.  In fact, Path.Combine in .NET is designed for it : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @17of26 The algorithm is the one used for referring to a path/file from a path, what else would make sense for combining paths? There is only the one algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

I do not find Join/Merge intuitive.  My preference is to omit support for ignoring absolute paths entirely, but to offer a trim function.  This could either be a member of Path or a separate utility function.  A member of path would remove leading and trailing whitespace and slashes (and possibly handle `..`).  With a utility function, you would provide an overload which supported either a predicate (the approach taken by Boost) or a char array (the approach taken by C#) in order to determine which characters to trim.

That being said, I've spent far more time with C# than C++, so my preferences are heavily C# oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your function, given a starting path and a potentially relative path, returns the resulting path.

Yes, `combine` would make sense, as a static member of the `Path` class. Still, why do you make it a member-function?
If you want a member-function, seems like it should be a two-argument-constructor.

`combinePaths` is a good name for a free function.

---

As an aside, a function to insert the platforms path-separator between passed path-components is quite useless, you can provide the separator as a constant string and use a general-purpose string-splicing method without any problem.

Though consider whether you don't simply want to use `/` (forward-slash) as path-separator internally and translate that to `\` on the fly on windows for presentation and such. Most of the time, you can leave that conversion to the WINAPI, as [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx):

> *Note*  File I/O functions in the Windows API convert "`/`" to "`\`" as part of converting the name to an NT-style name, except when using the "`\\?\`" prefix as detailed in the following sections.